# Convergence of the sequence $x_n=\frac{(\alpha+1)^n+(\alpha -1)^n}{{(2\alpha)}^n}$ for $\alpha >0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $\alpha >0$ and consider the sequence
$x_n=\frac{(\alpha+1)^n+(\alpha -1)^n}{{(2\alpha)}^n}$, n=1,2,3...

Then $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n$ is

(A) 0 for any $\alpha>0$

(B) 1 for any $\alpha>0$

(C) 0 or 1 depending on what $\alpha>0$ is

(D) 0, 1 or $\infty$ depending on what $\alpha>0$ is

My point is if $0<\alpha<\frac{1}{2}$ the expression $(\alpha-1)^n$ may oscillate and thus option (d) ,which is most appropriate, might not exactly be true.

Comment: Consider $\alpha=1$, $\alpha=2$ and $\alpha=1/2$.

Comment: I got all the three values mentioned in option (d). My query is what if the sequence oscillates at $n\rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 2):

$x_n$ consists of two parts $(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\alpha})^n$ and $(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\alpha})^n$. The following result is correct for $\alpha>0$:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\alpha})^n=
\begin{cases}
1&,\quad \alpha=1\\
0&,\quad \alpha>1\\
\infty&,\quad \alpha<1\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\alpha})^n=
\begin{cases}
0&,\quad \alpha>\frac{1}{3}\\
\text{oscillates between $-1$ and $1$}&,\quad \alpha=\frac{1}{3}\\
\text{oscillates between $-\infty$ and $\infty$}&,\quad \alpha<\frac{1}{3}\\
\end{cases},
$$
hence
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=
\begin{cases}
0&,\quad \alpha>1\\
1&,\quad \alpha=1\\
\infty&,\quad \alpha<1
\end{cases}
$$
and option (d) is correct.